# How long do I have to collect rent in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly

Player A lands on my property, and I'm not paying attention.  The rule book states:

> The owner may not collect the rent if he/she fails to ask for it before
> the second player following throws the dice

I always interpreted that to mean once Player B rolled the dice I was out of luck (i.e., Player A--who owes me money--was the first player and Player B was the second).  But I can definitely see that being interpreted as giving me until Player C rolls the dice, being the second player to play *after* Player A.

Comment: I was trying to edit the existing answer to explain itself without getting bogged down in dictionaries, and realized I should double-check: can you explain how you read this as referring to player B? My guess is you read it as something like "the second player, i.e. the player following"?

Comment: @Jefromi Yes; I'm the first player, you are the second player, following me.    Granted my punctuation changes the meaning to be more what I intended.

Comment: second player following != second following player

Comment: @thumbtackthief: Please compare "Let's eat, Grandpa." and "Let's eat Grandpa.". One cannot add and remove commas at a whim, and retain meaning. Other examples [here](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/a-light-hearted-look-at-how-punctuation-can-change-meaning/).

Answer (score 16):

Suppose the players are Anne, Bill, Charlize, David, Elizabeth, and Fred.

Anne rolls the dice, moves her counter and lands on Fred's property. Fred fails to notice.

The players following Anne are Bill, Charlize, David, etc. Bill is the first player following Anne, and Charlize is the second. So Fred must notice and request rent before Charlize rolls.

A specific scenario:

The *first following player*, Bill, now rolls the dice and moves his counter. Any transactions are processed as necessary.

The *second following player*, Charlize, now reaches for the dice as Fred notices Anne's counter and request payment. As the *second following player*, Charlize, has not yet ***thrown*** the dice, the request by Fred is in order and must be honoured.

---

The question is now asked: "why the second following instead of first following player?"

Simply, to prevent a pair of players from sitting down and guaranteeing that the one in elder position wins. Under a "first following" rule, if Alfred and Betty sit down beside each other, with Alfred rolling first, then Betty simply must be *very fast* at rolling the dice to ensure that Alfred never pay rent.

Next game, Alfred and Betty switch places and  Betty is guaranteed to never pay rent.

And so on. This is called "*The Bum's Rush*".

There are also more subtle ways to play it, where the younger hand *rolls very quickly* only at strategic moments in the game. Same effect, with only a very slight reduction in effectiveness.

Comment: I'd also point out that linguistics aside, this is a terrible, confusing way to play.  "Hey five minutes ago you landed on my property, even though a complete turn has passed of other things happening, you owe me $500."

Comment: @thumbtackthief" Rules exist for a reason. You always have the option of declaring, and playing by, any house rules you and your friends agree to. But when two players start colluding to give the *Bum's Rush* to another player, your group may suddenly be one member short for a good game.  Good general advice is always to be sure you know the ***why*** of a rule before changing it.

Comment: Anne lands on Fred's property; she owes rent that will put her out of the game.  Fred doesn't notice.  Bill goes, and has to pay $1000 rent to Anne.  Now Fred notices, but now Anne has more than enough to pay.  What happens?  Be sure you know the *why* of a rule before changing it.

Comment: Transactions occur in their proper order. Bill now owes $1000 to Frederick, the current and proper owner of the property gained in Anne's bankruptcy proceedings.

Comment: @ForgetIWasEverHere I agreed with you up until "Bill now owes $1000 to Frederick" I don't see how the "proper order" is anything other than the order that rent money is requested. Allowing for undoing of transactions to correct for missed rent sounds like a really poor way of doing things and doesn't seem to be supported by the rules.

Comment: If you want this to be a good answer, I would strongly suggest just concisely explaining why the phrase means what it does, something along the lines of "if the players are A, B, C, D, ... and A should collect rent, then the players following A are B, C, D, ..., so B is the first player following, and C is the second player following." The organization and verbosity of your answer unfortunately make it less clear, and your attitude toward the OP's request for reference/explanation is, well, not what we do here.

Comment: Hey folks, this might be a good time to take a break from this thread, and if you want to come back to it, focus on improving the answer.

Comment: Like providing a source for "The Bum's Rush" which I could not find through any amount of Googling to have anything to do with dice-throwing or game-playing.

Comment: How does this work in a two player game though? If Alice and Bob are playing, and Alice lands on Bob's property, but Bob doesn't notice. Then Bob plays a full turn, and the dice go back to Alice. Bob can request rent from Alice **before** he throws the dice ... but can he request it after as well? As Alice is about to leave the spot she's due rent on?

Answer (score 2):

If Player A lands on your property, you have until Player C rolls the dice to demand rent.

The [2009 Monopoly World Championship rules](https://www.monopolydocumentary.com/fileshare/Monopoly%20World%20Championship%20FAQs%20%28Final%29.doc) have an explicit example of this:

> **7. How long do I have to ask for rent?**
>
> In Championship Monopoly, you can ask for rent until the second player to your left throws the dice. This is to encourage good sportsmanship.
> **E.G.** Player A lands on your property, Player B takes a turn. You can still ask for rent. As soon as the dice leave Player C’s hand, you have missed your chance.

Of note, this was not always the case.  Modern monopoly rules, such as [this](https://%20hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf) and [this](https://hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) say:

> The owner may not collect the rent if he/she fails to ask for it before the second player following throws the dice.

However, some older monopoly sets, such as [this](https://hasbro.com/common/instruct/Monopoly_Vintage.pdf) say:

> If the owner fails to ask for rent before the next throw of the dice, no rent is collected.

The game likely changed to say "second player following" to prevent players from being able to move play artificially fast to skip rent payments, such as the process described by [@ForgetIWasEverHere in this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/39272/9999).

Comment: Note: The rulesets you label modern are from 2007 and 1997, respectively. The current rules (see link in my answer) are from 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguous phrase only exists in some editions/versions.

The current rules use the unambiguous phrasing

> If they don’t ask before the next player rolls the dice, you don’t have to pay!

(Current rules as per [Hasbro](https://instructions.hasbro.com/en-us/instruction/Monopoly-Classic-Game))

Other editions have alternated between this unambiguous phrasing and the original phrasing. This is most likely due to oversight (or lack thereof), but a case could be made that this helps show which meaning is intended:

[1972](http://a-garbutt1215-sb.blogspot.com/2013/09/monopoly-rules-1972.html):

> Note: If the owner fails to ask for his rent before the next throw of the dice no rent may be collected.

[2005](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Monopoly_Vintage.pdf):

> IF THE OWNER FAILS TO ASK FOR RENT BEFORE THE NEXT THROW OF THE DICE, NO RENT IS COLLECTED.