# Breaking an unknown rule had major effect on our Monopoly game, how do we resolve it after we learn the rule?

Tags: monopoly

I owned Whitechapel and Old Kent Road, both with hotels. My friend owned Mayfair and Park Lane with no developments.

We traded and I gave a further two million dollars to him. Nothing was said about the fact this was an illegal trade because we didn't know there was a rule that you can't trade properties with houses on them.

Later in the game, another player asked if you could sell properties back to the bank. It was only during the search to that question we discovered that the above was an illegal trade which has affected everyone.

If the rule was unknown until later in the game, do you play on as no one had brought it up when it occured? Does the whole game become invalid? Do you play on or quit?

Is there an official rule about not being able to argue a rule once a turn has passed?

Comment: So you ask if there is a rule that rules the situation when you disregarded a rule.

Comment: I'd just correct any issues, which should still be possible, as the correct way to go about that trade would have been to sell the houses [adding their value to the trade] then rebuild after the trade.

Comment: This question can be asked about any rule in any game; the answer will not be specific to Monopoly.

Comment: @GendoIkari True but some games have specific ways of dealing with broken rules. In fact there are even games where cheating is encouraged, like Munchkin.

Comment: I would honestly suggest playing a game that isn't monopoly.

Answer (score 8):

The rules don't specify how to handle this, but I would fall back on the [**second following player rolls the dice**](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39267/how-long-do-i-have-to-collect-rent-in-monopoly/39272#39272) provision for collecting rent.

When learning a new game, there will always be occasions when a rule is initially missed, and then discovered later. There must be limits on how far back to attempt reconciliation, so adopting a limit already in the Rules is a sensible compromise.

First games should always be recognized as a learning exercise for all players; complete this game quickly, and offer a prompt rematch to assuage any ill feelings. Remember that making the mistake once, in a game situation, is likely the very best way to remember the rule going forward.